# How do I search in previous rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

```
+-----+--------+---------+-------+--+
| row | object |  date   |  size |  |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+--+
|   1 |     17 | 19.6.3  | 6 **  |  |
|   2 |     17 | 19.5.2  | 5 *   |  |
|   3 |     17 | 19.1.1  | 3     |  |
|   4 |     17 | 18.6.6  | 5 **  |  |
|   5 |     17 | 17.4.4  | 4     |  |
|   6 |     88 | 19.3.12 | 2     |  |
+-----+--------+---------+-------+--+
```

The row and asterisks are just for the benefit of this question.

I have managed to calculate previous date and previous size for each row within an object using lag function (so for row 1 prev date = 19.5.2, prev size = 5).

(Although these values are not stored in the DB.)

Now I want to do something like the following pseudo code:

For an object,

if size has increased since prev date (for the above example data, true for rows 1, 2, 4) (easy to calculate)

Is the current size one that has not been encountered prior to that row’s date (true for rows 1 and 4) then set Flag = true for this row. (This is where I'm stuck)

I thought a SUBQUERY and/or window ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING might help, but do not know how to begin.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when size > lag(size) over (partition by object order by date) and
                  row_number() over (partition by object, size order by date) = 1
             then 1   -- true
             else 0   -- false
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon and so speedy! Unfortunately I can't test it till tomorrow morning.